# How to sendtext in ckeditor through htmlunitdriver in webdriver

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver, htmlunit-driver

How to send text in  `ckeditor` through `htmlunitdriver` in web driver? Below code is working for `firefoxdriver` but not for `htmlunitdriver` .

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='scayt_0']")));

WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));

 elem.click();

 elem.sendKeys("djkds");

driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Please use latest version, also can you post your complete case (with URL), so others can reproduce your issue?